# Chrome Extension: Redirects to an image in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension where when someone goes on a specific website, they get redirected to an image (within the directory of the extension) that get loaded in the browser.

I don't know how to do that using JS. 
here is the JS, myScript file:

```
var Image = new Array();
Image[0] = ["images/Buddha.jpg"];
Image[1]=["images/josephcampbell.jpg"];
Image[2]= ["images/Preparation.jpg"];
Image[3]=["images/swami.jpg"];
Image[4]=["images/waltwhitman.jpg"];
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
var img = Image[randomIndex];
var imgurl = chrome.runtime.getURL(img);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look for examples how to use chrome.webRequest with `redirectUrl`

Comment: Hello, I checked for an example and then followed what the code was doing, but mine is still not working. In the background scripts.js it says that chrome has not been declared before use.
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function() {
    
    var i = Math.round(Math.random() * img.length);
    return {redirectUrl: img[i]};
  });
  while the script file has the img

Comment: Browser doesn't say that so either ignore or configure your IDE properly. If the new code doesn't work add it to the question with manifest.json

Comment: "permissions": [
          
          "webRequest","webRequestBlocking",
         "*://www.facebook.com/*","*://www.netflix.com/*","*://www.9gag.com/*","*://www.reddit.com/*","*://www.youtube.com/*","*://www.twitter.com/*","*://www.amazon.com/*","*://www.tumblr.com/*"
             ],
"background":{
    "scripts":["myScript.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"content_scripts":[
    {
    "matches":["*://www.facebook.com/*","*://www.netflix.com/*","*://www.9gag.com/*","*://www.reddit.com/*","*://www.youtube.com/*","*://www.twitter.com/*"],
    "js":["theImages.js"]

Comment: I left out some code because that isn't the issue. Perhaps I'm not accessing the API properly.